# NetBeans Platform do nothing on close

Tags: java, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am buliding an NetBeans Platform application. When the user clicks on the X of the main window I want the application to do nothing and show a password JDialog. If the password is correct close the app, else do not close the app. How do I do this? I've created a Listener class that will show the password JDialog, but how do I stop the application from closing? Similar to JFrame's setDefaultCloseOperation, and setting it to do nothing on close.

```
    public class Listener extends WindowAdapter {

        private Frame frame;

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event) {
            frame = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
            frame.setSize(946, 768);
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            ShutDownMainWindowJDialog shutDownMainWindowJDialog;
            shutDownMainWindowJDialog = new ShutDownMainWindowJDialog(null, true);
            shutDownMainWindowJDialog.exeShutDownMainWindowJDialog();
            shutDownMainWindowJDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            shutDownMainWindowJDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

    @Override
    public void restored() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame frame = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
                frame.addWindowListener(new Listener());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How? JFrame someJFrame = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow(); gives me an error

Comment: Create a new JFrame? haha. `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` But my answer below works if you are committed to just using a `Frame`. You can have a class that extends `JFrame` and use that for your main window.

Comment: @jadrijan Does this new code work? This is how it should be done. If you are seeing errors then you should post an **Edit** that shows the errors you're receiving.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I got it working by overriding the closing() method of the ModuleInstall. It is all fairly simple, but when one is not familiar with a framework it is all difficult. Thanks for your help as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy. So create module with installer and overwrite method closing (may by), then show your dialog and return false (not close app). Jirka

So this is conclusion:
add to your module installer/activator

```
package master;

import org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall;

/**
 * Manages a module's lifecycle. Remember that an installer is optional and
 * often not needed at all.
 */

public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

 @Override
 public void close() {
  //your module shutdown
 }

 @Override
 public boolean closing() {

 // this is place for your Dialog() and return:
 //
 //        true if you want to enable close the app
 //        other return false
/*
 if you force shutdown app try LifecycleManager.getDefault().exit();
 System.exit(0) is very dummy, because it does not respect betweenmodule dependencyis

 }  
}
```

Jirka

Comment: I figured this out over a month ago, but anyways thank you for your answer I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

In your `windowClosing()` get the password from the user and `dispose()` the frame if it is correct.

```
public class PasswordToClose extends WindowAdapter {

  private JFrame frame;

  public PasswordToClose(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password to close");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.addWindowListener(new PasswordToClose(frame));
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter password");
    if ("secret".equals(password)) {
      frame.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: He claims he can't use a JFrame, I already suggested that he just use the JFrame and its setDefaultClose, but he didn't like it.

Comment: Hello, I think, that thinking about windowClosing is not good, because NB is framework based on module system. Yust one module is for "closing action" ;-) Simple use overwride closing or close. Jirka